# In JDK 1.3 String.replaceall() not working. any alternate solution

Tags: java, string, str-replace, replaceall

I am trying to run below mentioned code in JDK 1.3 and giving error as JDK1.3 does not support string.replaceall

```
strtobeReplaced = strtobeReplaced.replaceall("&","&amp;");

strtobeReplaced = strtobeReplaced.replaceall("].value","");
```

can anyone suggest alternate code in java 1.3 for the same.

Comment: Since regex wasn't added until Java 4, you'd need a third-party regex library. Or upgrade away from that ancient relic version of Java *(released in 2000, replaced by Java 4 in 2002)*. Or, since you're not actually using regex, write your own loop using `indexOf` and `substring` with a `StringBuffer`.

Comment: `replaceAll` was added in Java 1.4. You could backport `Pattern` and `Matcher`, but why would you bother? You know 1.3 has been end-of-life for over a decade?

Answer (score 1):

[StringBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) has been around since the inception of Java

So perhaps use a simple loop and use the `sb.append()` method as necessary.

```
static String replace(char rep, String replacement, String word) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        if(word.charAt(i) == rep){
            sb.append(replacement);
        }
        else{
            sb.append(word.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

**Caveat:** this is just a guideline and will only work if the *to be replaced* section is an individual character, you'll need to work around this idea if it's multiple characters.

[Example](https://ideone.com/GSGfAu)

Comment: Close.  But `rep` needs to be a `String` for the 2nd use-case

Comment: @StephenC ah so it does, I never actually looked at much more than the title. I guess now it's more just a guideline of an idea of how to do it :) - so added a caveat...